# Why Sublime Text 2 doesn't updates folder's modification date?

Tags: sublimetext2

Here is a text file: test/foo.txt

When I use Sublime Text 2 to edit and save it, the 'test' folder's modification date doesn't change.

So if I want update the folder's date, need to run "touch test/" in Terminal. It drive me crazy.

Any way to do that automatically ?

Answer (score 3):

The modification time of a directory will be updated only when a file is added, removed or renamed. Changing the content of the files in that directory simply won't trigger that.

Comment: But Vim, Emacs and other editors trigger that when edit files.

Comment: Yes, they do, which indicates that they create some kind of temp/.swp file while you editing the file in that directory, thus causing the update on the modification time of that directory. Sublime text doesn't work in that way.

Answer (score 2):

You can change that on your preference file.
This is known as atomic save.

On your preference file, change it to:

```
"atomic_save": false
```

This will touch the file every time you save it.